# What is the difference between Yuga Dharma and Santana Dharma? What is the Yuga Dharma for each Yuga?

Tags: scripture, dharma, worship, yuga, kali-yuga

I'm really confused about the Yuga Dharma of each Yuga. Some say Daan is the Yuga Dharma of Kaliyuga while some say chanting the name of God. Someone please explain this concept in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Some say Daan is the Yuga Dharma of Kaliyuga while some say chanting
> the name of God. Someone please explain this concept in detail.

Both these statements are correct. One is found in the Smritis and the other primarily in the Puranas.

> Manu Smriti 1.86. In the Krita age the chief (virtue) is declared to
> be (the performance of) austerities, in the Treta (divine) knowledge,
> in the Dvapara (the performance of) sacrifices, **in the Kali
> liberality (charity) alone.**

In Kali Yuga Nama Japa is also given great importance. And, this view is mainly found in the Puranas.

The [book "Dharma Bindu"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/Dharma%20Bindu.pdf) (pp 13-14) quotes some relevant verses from Puranas (like Vishnu Purana and Narada Purana):

> **Vishnu Purana:**
>
> Sarve Brahma vadavyanti sampraptetun Kaloau yuge,
>  Naanu tishthanti
> Maitreya shishnodara parayanaah/
>  Yada yadaasataam haanih
> Vedamargaanu saarinaam,
>  Tadaa tadaa Kaler vriddhih anumeyaa
> vichakshanaih//
>
> Veda Vyaasauvaacha: Yatkrute dashabhirvarshaih tretaayaam vaayanenatu
> Dvaapare tacchamaasena hyahoraatrena tatlalou/
>  Dhyaayan Krite
> yajan yagjnaih Tretaayaam Dwapare archayan,
>  Yadaapnoti tadaapnoti
> Kalou samkeerta Keshavam/
>
> **Naaradiye:**
>
> Hare Keshava Govinda Vaasudeva Janaarddana,
>  Iteetayanti nityam
> sahitaan badhate Kalih// 
> Shiva Shankara Rudreti Nilakantha
> Trilochana,
>  Iteerayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate
> Kalih/
> Shiva Shankara Rudreti Neelakantha Trilochana,
> Iteerayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate Kalih/
>
> Vishnu Purana details Yuga dharmas as follows: In Kali Yuga, every one
> discusses about Brahma Jnaana but none is really interested in it
> since they are overwhelmed of selfishness, centric pysche and sex but
> none really is serious in favour of Brahma Jnaana; as and when there
> occurs a danger to the Virtuous, there is the upgradation of evil
> forces and infringement of virtue, and the signs of Kali Yuga become
> prominent and clear. Vyasa states: What ever deeds of virtue are
> performed in ten years in Krita yuga are as dispensed with or equal to
> those peformed in one Ayana on Treta Yuga, one month in one Dvapara
> yuga and even in single day-night on Kali Yuga. The rewards of virtue
> by of Tapas during KritaYuga are as good as Yagjnas in Treta yuga,
> worships in DvaparaYuga and even ‘Samkeertanas’ rendering Sacred Songs
> in Kali yuga.
>
> Narada Brahmarshi that states the soulful singing of Narayana as: Here
> Keshava Govinda Vaasudeva Janardana 14 Iteerayanti nityam sahitaan
> baadhate Kalih/ Or alternatively as Shiva Shankara Rudreti Neelakantha
> Tricochana, Itirtayanti ye nityam sahitaan baadhate Kalih/ That is
> either render Hari Smarana or Hara smarana as above! Kali Yuga would
> never ever torment sincere prayers with the naamas as mentioned above.
> Such indeed are the Yuga Dharmas!

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot!