# Path to salvation in kaliyug

Tags: vedas, mantras, dharma

What should the "fated" humans in this kaliyug do to attain the divine salvation once and for all? What's to happen to those after Salvation and to those who couldn't attain?

Comment: Does this answer it? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42502/what-is-the-difference-between-yuga-dharma-and-santana-dharma-what-is-the-yuga?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I need a straight answer. But thanks for the extra info.